# Running a program as root on Android

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung

I have followed the guide at [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1955423) for a Samsung Galaxy Note II, and used "option 2" and flashed the firmware using `heimdall flash --RECOVERY recovery.img --CACHE cache.img` in Linux.

This gave me a SuperSU program, which I could execute. After executing it immediately wanted to update. I allowed it. It required a reboot, I allowed that. The program asked if it should attempt to install by the "normal" or CWM method. I picked CWM.

The device started up in the CWM minimal OS, but it was not apparent to me what option the user should take at this point to proceed. I tried various options, like installing from cache or sd card, but there didn't appear to be any file to install.

I rebooted again, started SuperSU again. I selected "Install SuperSU into /system". The program needed to reboot again, this time I was not given the option of how to install it ("normal" or CWM).

After reboot, I started SuperSU again. The option was still available to "Install SuperSU into /system", it is unclear if this means SuperSU has not successfully installed, or if this option is always available in case you need to repeat the procedure after an update.

I downloaded the *Titanium Backup* program which as I understand required root access. When executing Titanium Backup, I was prompted by SuperSU if I wished to grant root access. I clicked yes. The program appeared to function properly.

My questions are:

1. What action is the user supposed to take within CWM when SuperSU requests to reboot using this method?
2. Is the choice "Install SuperSU into /system" supposed to still be possible to select after a successful install?
3. How do I run an arbitrary program as root? What I wanted to do in the first place was to get a terminal to run as root. I have already a program called "Terminal Emulator" installed. How do I make "Terminal Emulator" execute as root?
4. Is it normal for SuperSU to "close" itself spontaneously while looking through the settings? I think once it updated itself while I was in the settings, but I'm not sure.

Comment: 3: For the terminal emulator, a workaround is to simply execute "su" (of course) program after executing the terminal emulator itself. However, is there no way to execute the terminal emulator itself, as root?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194725/run-android-program-as-root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, that's 4 questions in one. Our site works best with one question per post; but let me try:

1. **How to install via CWM (custom recovery)?**
   usually, it's "install update.zip from SDCard" when the deal is to "install something via recovery". By default, there should be an `update.zip` file in the root of the SDCard, which you then navigate to and select.
   Hint: I always update it via *Google Play* (the "normal way"). Works smoothly, never had trouble, doesn't require a reboot.
2. **Is the choice "Install SuperSU into /system" supposed to still be possible to select after a successful install?**
   I'd say "No", but it depends. This usually *moves* the app from `/data` (user-space) to `/system` (system-space). After having moved it, it should no longer be in its original location. But depending on how updates are installed (SuperSU e.g. updates via *Google Play*, like any other app), this update could again end up in user-space, in which case the user might wish to "repeat" the system integration.
3. **How do I run an arbitrary program as root?**
   Two-fold. First, "arbitrary programs" (apps) must request root access themselves, you cannot make them "run as root". That's a little different when it comes to the command line: prefixing your commands with `su` *makes* the terminal app requesting root access. So you could e.g. list all directories below `/data` using `su ls /data` and succeed (while a simple `ls /data` wouldn't be able to access all files/sub-directories here).
4. **Is it normal for SuperSU to "close" itself spontaneously while looking through the settings?**
   I've never experienced that, and I'm using SuperSU on one of my devices for a year now (the others have chainfire's SuperUser). But I must admit I'm not often calling it directly and stay there for longer. I mostly only see the access requests of apps, or the update recommendation via *Play* :)